# How to edit the contributor's commit in a pull request in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I made a pull request to some repository and the maintainer told me that my commit message was wrong, but he had already changed that message for the right one. I wonder how he did that if he had no write access to my repository.

**EDIT:**

I know he can fetch my branch, merge locally and amend my commit message but he didn't do that. The commit hadn't been merged yet but my commit message had changed.

Comment: GitHub now has an option that gives maintainers write access to your pull request’s branch; you might have checked that. Commits can be changed freely as they’re being applied to the repo, though, so write access wouldn’t have even been necessary if your branch didn’t change.

Comment: If you haven't pushed, then you can do `git amend -m "Another message"`.
If you have already pushed this would require to force push.

Comment: He doesn't have to own write access to your repository because the change he has made is in his repository. Fetch the branch and the commits, which your pull request has provided, into his repository first, and then amend the commit message and merge the amended revision into the target branch. If this repository is not the server-side repository, he needs to sync this repository with the server-side repository in addition. The detailed procedure in GitHub may be different. But the main actions are about the same.

Comment: I know he can merge and amend but he didn't do that. The commit wasn't merged yet.